# Remove whole sentences from dataset

Tags: r, string

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| output |
| --- |
| Others. Specify (separate by comma if there is more than one): |
| Everyone cries/has feelings,Others. Specify (separate by comma if there is more than one): |
| Family upbringing |
| Everyone cries/has feelings,Others. Specify (separate by comma if there is more than one): |
| Did not say |

How can I remove the sentence "Others. Specify (separate by comma if there is more than one):" from the dataset? I've tried

```
gsub("Others. Specify (separate by comma if there is more than one):", "", datset$output)
```

and str_remove_all() but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by adding `fixed=TRUE`, which means to match the pattern as is

```r
gsub("Others. Specify (separate by comma if there is more than one):", 
     "", 
     datset$output, 
     fixed = TRUE)
#> [1] ""                             "Everyone cries/has feelings,"
#> [3] "Family upbringing"            "Everyone cries/has feelings,"
#> [5] "Did not say"
```

Second option would be to escape all special characters which in your case are the `.` and in particualar the `()`, e.g. in a regex `()` are used to create a capturing group. Hence to match a e.g. `(` you have to use `\\(`:

```
gsub("Others\\. Specify \\(separate by comma if there is more than one\\):", "", datset$output)
```

**DATA**

```
datset <- data.frame(
  output = c(
    "Others. Specify (separate by comma if there is more than one):",
    "Everyone cries/has feelings,Others. Specify (separate by comma if there is more than one):", "Family upbringing",
    "Everyone cries/has feelings,Others. Specify (separate by comma if there is more than one):", "Did not say"
  )
)
```